# Elementor Navigation Mobile View

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

My website is designed in Elementor and I am using the default nav widget. In mobile view, the hamburger menu is going under the content. I have tried using z-index on different options but still can't figure out the issue. Your help will be appreciated.

[Website Link](https://tesssystems.com/petro)

[image: menu screenshot]

Comment: Can you show us exactly where? Mobile view in Chrome seems fine - https://nimb.ws/5dtfs1

Comment: I have shared the screenshot. It goes under the slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this css to page:

```
.elementor-12 .elementor-element.elementor-element-db0b507{
    z-index:9999;
}
```

note: when the main parent is in the back of other layers(at the level of the parent), the children's z-index can not be placed on the top of other layers which are at the same level as the parent.

Comment: I tried but it is not working.

Comment: I'm sure it works. I tried it on your site. In addition, I had this problem before. You can try this with `!important`